# How to run commands on ruby console using JsCh

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsch

I am using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library to connect to a `remote shell` using `ssh`. I'm able to run unix commands and I am getting output also.

I want to know how do I run `Rails` commands after running `bundle exec rails c`, can I interact with console after switching to `Rails Console`

I am passing all the `commands` in an array like:

```
["cd code/mycode", "pwd"] --> It outputs as /code/mycode which is fine
["cd code/mycode", "pwd", "bundle exec rails c", "rails command"] --> gives error.
```

so it gives output till pwd later when I run rails comands it gives error.

Comment: Since `JSch` is a complete implementation of `ssh`, the answer is “yes.” Why wouldn’t you try it yourself?

Comment: yeah I've tried, I am passing all the commands in an array, it work quite wel till the point I am giving only unix commands, once I switch on rails console, it started giving `bash: 644656: command not found`

Comment: `JSch` won’t automatically load `.profile` / `.bashrc` ⇒ the remote shell needs the PATH (and probably smth else) be updated to point to preinstalled ruby / gems. Currently the remote shell can not find `bundle`.

Comment: yes @mudasobwa is right. Your Jsch Shell will not be able to recognize what "bundle" is, until you specify the path of this program.

Comment: Please edit your question  to include your code which uses jsch to connecto the server and run these commands.